# SwiftUI IAP invalid product identifiers error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

Dear Stack Overflow Community, I'm new here and I know this question has been asked quite a few times here. Nevertheless, I haven't found a solution to my problem in my SwiftUI app for days.
I have included a nonconsumable in-app purchase in my app and get the error: **Invalid Product Identifiers found**.
This is what I've done so far:

1. I have signed the App Store Connect Paid Apps Agreement.
2. I created an in-app purchase in my app in AppStore Connect and filled out all the data
   [(except for the verification information for Apple, that's why it says "Missing Metadata")](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZZhB.png)
3. [I added the in-app purchase capability to my app's target in XCode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVGLh.png)
4. I created a StoreManager class that loads my products etc:

```
class StoreManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver {
    
    @AppStorage("unlimitedAccess") var unlimitedAccess = false

    @Published var products = [SKProduct]()
    @Published var transactionState: SKPaymentTransactionState?
    @Published var isRestoring = false
    @Published var showNoRestorablePurchaseAlert = false

    static let standart = StoreManager()
    
    
    private override init() {
        super.init()
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
    }
    
    // MARK: - Load the products
    func loadProducts(with id: [String]) {
        let request = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: Set(id))
        request.delegate = self
        request.start()
    }
    
    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        if !response.products.isEmpty {
            for fetchedProduct in response.products {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.products.append(fetchedProduct)
                }
            }
        }
        
        for invalidIdentifier in response.invalidProductIdentifiers {
            print("Invalid identifiers found: \(invalidIdentifier)")
        }
    }
    
    func request(_ request: SKRequest, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Request did fail: \(error)")
    }
    
    // MARK: - Purchase and restore
    func purchaseProduct(product: SKProduct) {
        if !isRestoring {
            if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
                let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
                SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func restoreProducts() {
        if transactionState != .purchasing {
            isRestoring = true
            SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
        }
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction in transactions {
            switch transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchasing:
                transactionState = .purchasing
                
            case .purchased:
                // Purchase completed
                unlimitedAccess = true
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .purchased
                
            case .restored:
                // Purchase restored
                unlimitedAccess = true
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .restored
                isRestoring = false
                
            case .failed, .deferred:
                // Transaction failed
                print("Payment Queue Error: \(String(describing: transaction.error))")
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
                transactionState = .failed
                
            default:
                queue.finishTransaction(transaction)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        if queue.transactions.count == 0 {
            showNoRestorablePurchaseAlert.toggle()
        }
        
        isRestoring = false
    }
    
    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError error: Error) {
        isRestoring = false
    }
}


extension SKProduct {
    var localizedPrice: String? {
        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        
        numberFormatter.locale = priceLocale
        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
        
        return numberFormatter.string(from: price)
    }
}
```

5. I called the `StoreManager.standart.loadProducts(with: ["xxx"])` method when my app being initialized:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ProTimerApp: App {

    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        UIView.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIAlertController.self]).tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.16, green: 0.67, blue: 0.89, alpha: 1)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = LocalNotificationManager.shared
        StoreManager.standart.loadProducts(with: ["xxx"])
    }
}
```

Note: The xxx ist just a placeholder. I used the right product identifier for sure.
6. I tested my app with my own iPhone and with the simulator but I just got the message "Invalid Product Identifiers found: xxx".

I would be very happy about help and I would be happy if you could appreciate how much effort I put into this question, because I'm also new here and don't know how everything works here yet.
Greetings!

Comment: In the IAP in App Store Connect there is a metadata section that requires an image all the way to the bottom you are likely missing that. Scroll all the way to the bottom of the screen in the screenshot and upload the image.

Comment: Hey @loremipsum do you mean the optional promotional image? This is as I said optional and can not cause the error...

Comment: No further down there is an approval section

Comment: @loremipsum do you mean the test information with the screenshot and the text for the apple review team?  Do you really think this ist necessary for my product to go online??

Comment: "Review Information" below "App Store Promotion (Optional)" there is a section there to upload a screenshot "A screenshot of the in-app purchase that clearly shows the item or service being offered. This screenshot is used for review only and isn't displayed on the App Store."

Comment: This is 100% necessary it needs to be submitted for approval along with the build that will use the purchase. The "Missing Metadata" note will switch to something about review and then "Approved" until it is "Approved" you can't use IAP in a production app.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/in-app-purchase-information

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/in-app-purchase-localization-statuses

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/reference/in-app-purchase-statuses This one describes the status

Comment: @loremipsum my state is now "Ready to Submit" but unfortunately I got the error "Invalid identifiers found" again...

Comment: Tough to help any more I am sure you have seen [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsresponse/1505985-invalidproductidentifiers) but that is the only other thing I would offer.

Comment: @loremipsum I have now added a storekit configuration file to my project in xcode and then synchronized this file with appstore connect. After my in-app purchase synchronized, the product with the product id was finally found. But why did I have to add this storekit configuration file to my project? I did not have to do that in the past

Comment: That is only for local testing when you are running the app in debug and attached to Xcode. Take a look at links [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/implementing_a_store_in_your_app_using_the_storekit_api) I was under the impression you were publishing already.

Comment: @loremipsum my app is already on the appstore but without any in-app purchases yet. Thanks for the link

Comment: @loremipsum what does "By default, StoreKit testing in Xcode is in a disable state" from your link mean?

Comment: I don’t have anything in specific from there just an FYI. There is a link to the video about the config file/StoreKit 2